# Finding CDF of Z = min{X,Y}

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $a$ be non-random. I have that $X$ and $Y$ are independent with the same density:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-(x-a)}\ \ x\geq a \\ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x<a \end{cases}$

I know that $P(Z>x) = P(X>x)P(Y>x) = e^{2(a-x)}$, and so $P(Z\leq x) = 1-e^{2(a-x)}$. However, I am wondering why I cannot say that $P(Z\leq x) = P(X\leq x)P(Y\leq x)$ directly, as this gives $(1-e^{a-x})^2$. Why must I first find $P
(Z>x)$?

Thanks!

Comment: It is true that $$\{\min\{X,Y\}>x\}=\{X>x\} \cap \{Y>x\}$$  However, it is not true that $\{\min\{X,Y\}\leq x\} = \{X\leq x\} \cap \{Y\leq x\}$.  A "similar-but-opposite" fact holds for $\max\{X,Y\}$.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the two events $\{\min(X,Y)<x\}$ and $\{X<x,Y<x\}$ are not equivalent. This holds for the $\max$ function and for the $\min$ function in opposite direction, i.e. $\{\min(X,Y)>x\}$ and $\{X>x,Y>x\}$ are equivalent.